# Laravel 6.2 - Пересоздание token при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: php, laravel, сессия, openserver, token

На локальной машине установлен Open Server
Через composer установлена Laravel 6.2
Стартовая страница открывается, роуты прописываются без проблем, миграции и остальное работает штатно

Проблема следующего характера:
При перезагрузке страницы (любой) в браузере всегда генерируется новый _token, что, по-видимому приводит к невозможности обработать отправку данных с форм проекта через POST - получаю ошибку 419. 
Предполагаю что POST уходит, но на стороне приёма данных csrf-токен генерится новый и не совпадает.

GET-отправка работает корректно.

Для хранения сессии пробовал и file и database.

При поиске наткнулся на длинные обсуждения попыток решить проблему - перечисленные способы не помогли.

Comment: Поставил ещё один эксперимент: наблюдаю появление новых файлов сессий в storage/framework/sessions , но файлов cookie на уровне браузера не прибавляется. Думаю, из-за отсутствия cookie ларавель решает, что безопасность под угрозой и создаёт новый токен.

Comment: В хоместеде все норм. Можно и перезагружать, и новые страницы создавать. Новых кук появляться и не должно, ведь все хранится в сессии. 
Вы в POST форме csrf токен прописали?

Comment: Дополните сообщение кодом : шаблона с POST формой, .env, session.php а то так- гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Вот еще советы https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583886/post-request-in-laravel-5-7-laravel-5-8-laravel-6-error-419-sorry-your